# Maven unable to read Jenkins environment variable

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Spring Boot project being built in Jenkins using a JenkinsFile pipeline script.

This Spring project uses the Spring Boot parent pom file.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
</parent>
```

I host all my dependencies, including the above parent, in a custom repository (happens to be proxied via Nexus). The definition for that repository looks like the following

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <url>${env.REPO_URL}</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

In my local development machine, I have set the `REPO_URL` environment variable to the URL of my repository. Locally, when I `mvn install` this works just fine. Maven resolves the repository URL to what I have defined in my environment, and no issues are encountered.

My problem arises when I attempt to use a JenkinsFile pipeline script in order to define the environment variable for `REPO_URL`. In the Jenkins scripts definitions, it looks like:

```
stringParam(name: 'REPO_URL', value: 'www.my.repo')
```

and I build in the JenkinsFile simply with:

```
sh "mvn clean package"
```

Maven will generate the following error:

`[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.my.project:my-project:1.0.0: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.1.RELEASE from/to nexus (${env.REPO_URL}): Cannot access ${env.REPO_URL} with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 12, column 10`

From the looks of the error message, it seems as if Maven does not have access to that environment variable. However, in my JenkinsFile if I do a `echo` then the variable will have the correct value populated. So clearly this variable is populating, but for some reason Maven is not parsing it correctly.

Is there anything I am doing incorrectly in using Jenkins to provide the environment variable to Maven for this repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

params are different. you can reference those as `params.REPO_URL` in your Jenkinsfile, but not in scripts you trigger. set up an environment variable like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  environment {
    REPO_URL = 'www.my.repo'
  }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        sh 'env | grep REPO_URL' // logs "REPO_URL=www.my.repo" for me
        sh 'mvn clean package'
      }
    }
  }
}
```